# How to create getters and setters for enum

Tags: java, enums, getter-setter, pojo

```
public enum EventTypeName
{
    MAIN_EVENT(new MainEvent()),
    MAIN_ADJUSTMENT_EVENT(new MainAdjustmentEvent()),
    CUSTOMER_EVENT(new CustomerEvent()),
     EventType eventType;

    private EventTypeName(EventType eventType)
    {
        this.eventType = eventType;
    }

    public EventType getEventType()
    {
        return eventType;
    }
}
```

I need to make getters and getters and setters for all new events to be declared in enum.

Comment: You have already done that successfully. When your enum class first loads, each of the named objects will be instantiated. As part of that instantiation a new subject that presumably is a subclass of `EventType` will be stored on the member field named `eventType`. (By the way, you might want to make that field `private`.) And you have a getter method to retrieve that `EventType` object.  `EventType et = EventTypeName.CUSTOMER_EVENT.getEventType() ;`  So what is your question?

Comment: It should not be this way                                                                  
    MAIN_EVENT(new MainEvent()),
    MAIN_ADJUSTMENT_EVENT(new MainAdjustmentEvent()),
    CUSTOMER_EVENT(new CustomerEvent()),                                                                         These should be created automatically when we call from others and the object should get assigned @BasilBourque

Comment: You can't dynamically create `enum` instances. enum can only be used if it is known at compile time what instances / values there are.

Comment: Can we make it done in any other way to make it create dynamically. My requirement is to make it create dynamically

Comment: Do you mean that you want each call to the `getEventType` method should return a new instance of one of the three subclasses? If so, that is possible,  but is likely a poor use of an enum.

Comment: Yes my requirement is that way for now.. let me know incase any possibilities @BasilBourque

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you want to instante a new subclass of `EventType` for each of the various enum objects, when the `getEventType` method is called.

In this situation, do not name your method with `get` prefix. In commonly used JavaBeans conventions, such a prefix indicates an accessory method to retrieve a property of the object. Given your intentions, a prefix of `new` or `make` may be more appropriate.

```java
public enum EventTypeName
{
    MAIN_EVENT , MAIN_ADJUSTMENT_EVENT , CUSTOMER_EVENT ;

    // Assumes MainEvent, MainAdjustmentEvent, and CustomerEvent are all subclasses of EventType. 
    public EventType makeEventType()
    {
        if ( this.equals( MAIN_EVENT ) ) { return new MainEvent() ; }
        if ( this.equals( MAIN_ADJUSTMENT_EVENT ) ) { return new MainAdjustmentEvent() ; }
        if ( this.equals( CUSTOMER_EVENT ) ) { return new CustomerEvent() ; }
    }
}
```

Usage.

```
EventType eventType = EventTypeName.MAIN_ADJUSTMENT_EVENT.makeEventType() ;
```

---

I get an unsettled feeling from looking at your code, suspecting a poor or flawed design. Likely from a misunderstanding of enums in Java. An enum should not be considered as a collection. You cannot define additional enum objects at runtime; they are defined at compile-time.

Comment: In this case if new event introduced as public event and class for that is created as PublicEvent. I need to instantiate a new object for that but it should not be from this enum but from where we call this  enum

Comment: @Fahd I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: from where I'm calling this enum should instantiate object and do the requirements. Like if there is a new event I should not come and add here in enum every time and call that..

Comment: @Fahd I suspect you misunderstand  the role of up enums in Java. Read the last two sentences of my revised Answer. If you want to change the set of objects at runtime, do not use enums, use a collection.

Comment: It is fine with any concept. May I know how can I solve my requirement in any concept @Basil Bourque